# How to get the coordinates along a line/path from left to right with Numpy Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, coordinates

Is there way to create a list with the coordinates of a drawn line in the right order (in this case: from left to right). Here is an [image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo9xW.png). Red pixels indicate the first coordinates and green pixels should be the last ones. The line is 1 pixel wide.

Getting the coordinates of every pixel of that line is easy with `numpy.where`, but how do I sort them appropriately? What happens if I had a shape like a circle instead of a line/path?

Comment: If you had a circle, what should that code actually output? There is no unique way to indicate a "first" or "last" coordinate, or even a direction.

Comment: One coordinate could serve as a starting point. I would for example define this starting point beforehand.

Comment: What are the ranges of your application?  For instance, if the curve (not *line*) is a function, sorting is trivial: sort by ordinal (x-value).

Comment: How is the curve represented?  If it's more complex than a functional plot, you may want to traverse from one point to the next with a stepping function: find the two points "adjacent" to the current one; pick the one you haven't already visited.  Iterate until done.

Comment: Maybe I should explain the problem I have more in detail: I have a binary mask of a cell. From that I can create an outline that is 1 pixel wide. Along this outline I would like to do an operation for every let's say 10th pixel. For this I would need a list with the coordinates in the right order (given a defined starting point since this is a closed shape). Going from one point to the next and checking for adjecent points was something I had in mind but have not tried yet.